# Unable to get flask socket io with react js socket.io-client working

Tags: reactjs, flask-socketio

I have wasted 2 days trying to get flask socket io with react js socket.io-client to work. I tried searching for similar questions on stackoverflow and even though I found them and tried the suggestions posted there, it didn't work.

Below are the versions of Flask and Flask-SocketIO

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ------------
aniso8601                 9.0.1
APScheduler               3.10.4
attrs                     23.1.0
bidict                    0.22.1
blinker                   1.7.0
cachelib                  0.9.0
certifi                   2023.11.17
cffi                      1.16.0
charset-normalizer        3.3.2
click                     8.1.7
colorama                  0.4.6
flasgger                  0.9.7.1
Flask                     3.0.0
Flask-Caching             2.1.0
Flask-Cors                4.0.0
Flask-JWT-Extended        4.5.3
Flask-RESTful             0.3.10
Flask-SocketIO            5.3.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy          3.1.1
gevent                    23.9.1
gevent-websocket          0.10.1
greenlet                  3.0.1
h11                       0.14.0
idna                      3.6
itsdangerous              2.1.2
Jinja2                    3.1.2
jsonschema                4.20.0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.11.2
MarkupSafe                2.1.3
mistune                   3.0.2
oauthlib                  3.2.2
packaging                 23.2
pycparser                 2.21
PyJWT                     2.8.0
python-engineio           4.8.2
python-socketio           5.11.0
pytz                      2023.3.post1
PyYAML                    6.0.1
referencing               0.32.0
requests                  2.31.0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1
rpds-py                   0.13.2
schedule                  1.2.1
scheduler                 0.8.5
simple-websocket          1.0.0
six                       1.16.0
SQLAlchemy                2.0.23
typeguard                 4.1.5
typing_extensions         4.8.0
tzdata                    2023.3
tzlocal                   5.2
urllib3                   2.1.0
Werkzeug                  3.0.1
wsproto                   1.2.0
zope.event                5.0
zope.interface            6.1
```

Below is the server side code, run.py

```
from app import create_app, db
from threading import Lock
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, \
    copy_current_request_context
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
from flask_cors import CORS

async_mode = None
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
count = 0

app = create_app()


@socketio.on("connect")
def connected():
    """event listener when client connects to the server"""
    print("client has connected")
    emit("connect", {"data": f"It is connected"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    # app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
    socketio.run(app, port=8080, debug=True)
```

And below is the react js with socket.io-client versions

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.1",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-daterange-picker": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-form-stepper": "^2.0.3",
    "react-gauge-chart": "^0.4.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.1.0-alpha.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.19.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

And below is the client side code to connect to the server

```
useEffect(() => {

    socket = io('localhost:8080',
        {
            extraHeaders: {
                "X-API-KEY": 'secret',
                "X-APP-NAME": 'testapp'
            }
        },
        {
            cors: {
              origin: "http://localhost:3000/",
            },
        }
    );
    console.log(socket);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log("Connected!");
    });

    // when connected, look for when the server emits the updated count
    socket.on('counter updated', function(countFromServer) {
      // set the new count on the client
      setCount(countFromServer);
    })

  }, []);
```

And the connected shows up as 'false' when I view the socket object value in the browser console.

[image: socket_connection_issue]

Can someone help me shed light on this?

Comment: Do you have the server logs? And a screenshot of your network tab showing the connection requests?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know if my experience was the same as yours but I had a similar experience. This isn’t a fix but was a workaround. Latest installs of flask and flask-socketio (python 3.11) and react from

> npx create-react-app

plus installing socket.io-client. I set up the bare minimum in flask and react to make the ws connection. Running this causes client websockets to continuously connect to flask (or flask to not complete the connection) with connect errors in chrome and the client never says it is connected.

I took the package-lock.json from the repo referenced here [websocket-app](https://medium.com/@adrianhuber17/how-to-build-a-simple-real-time-application-using-flask-react-and-socket-io-7ec2ce2da977) deleted and rebuilt the node modules with

> npm i react-scripts

and the websockets connect correctly.

Too frustrated at it right now to figure out what dependency is causing the problem.